# Search Returns no results

Tags: search, enterprise-search

When I perform a search nothing is returned. I have two Web Applications.

- Intranet
- My Sites

Intranet only has landing  page with the text *“This is a test”.* 
My Sites has imported 300 users from AD. I have filled in my profile.

When I search for my surname in enterprise search it returns nothing. When I search for test in search it returns nothing.

My Content source for search has the URL for both web applications. I have performed a full crawl.

My Search has Success 54 and All Errors as 0.

My search user has the “*Retrieve People Data for Search Crawlers*” selected on the User service.

In User policy for both web applicatiosn my search user has full read access.

What could I be missing to getting my content appearing in the search results?

**Update**

When I came into the office this morning in normal search i searched for my surname. It then asked "Did I Mean" surnameJ" (Our login names are surname first insitail of name). Clicking on this returned the 3 generated images of profile picture.

Searching for my surname in the people search still returned nothing.

Comment: Is the Search Service in the service proxy group associated with your web app?

Comment: Where would i check that?

Comment: Central Administration > Application Mangagement > Service Applications > Configure service application associations

Comment: Are all in the default group. All check boxes checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For search to index AD you need to make sure that in your content source that you have:

> sps3://servername

Results from AD (If all the other steps have been followed) should now appear.

Hat tip to http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/03/29/how-to-set-up-people-search-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx where I saw that you need to use a differnt protocol.